# disable bar button text color changes to white?

Tags: iphone, navigationbar, rightbarbuttonitem, navigationitem

Given below is image of my navigation bar, where right bar button is disable now. but when i disable it its text changes to white color. i don't want white color. Any solution of this.

First image when Edit button is enabled.
Other when Edit button is disabled.
Can we disable button without changes its text color in that case. many thanks in advance

this is for customizing bar button

```
 [[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTintColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:253.0/255.0 green:220.0/255.0 blue:135.0/255.0 alpha:1.0]];


[[UIBarButtonItem appearance] setTitleTextAttributes:
 [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
  [UIColor blackColor], UITextAttributeTextColor,
  [UIColor colorWithRed:1.0 green:1.0 blue:1.0 alpha:1.0], UITextAttributeTextShadowColor,
  [UIFont fontWithName:@"MyriadPro-Cond_0" size:16.0], UITextAttributeFont, nil]
                                            forState:UIControlStateNormal];
```

this is for bar button

```
 UIBarButtonItem *rightBarBtnEdit=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Edit" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(methodEdit:)];
[rightBarBtnEdit setTag:701];
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:rightBarBtnEdit];
```

this is disabling

```
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem.enabled = NO;
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: give your edite button code ...

Comment: post edit button code with the initial configuration of the edit button

Comment: hey i put the code too

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setTitleTextAttributes:forState:` should be called multiple times, for each state you wish to customise. At the moment you're calling it once, for `UIControlStateNormal`, for other states the values will be at their default.

Call it with `UIControlStateDisabled` as well, with whatever attributes you need.